# How to get all functions from frida javascript rpc.exports to python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, rpc, frida

I have a js file with some rpc.exports

```js
rpc.exports = {
    callfunctionsecret: callSecretFun,
    callfunctionsomethingelse: callSomethingElse,
}
```

I want to list ALL these functions in python, but I couldn't find a way to do it

```py
device = frida.get_usb_device()
pid = device.spawn([package_name])
device.resume(pid)
time.sleep(1)
session = device.attach(pid)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as jsfile:
        script = session.create_script(jsfile.read())
print(dir(script.exports))
# output
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_script']
# output doesn't contain "callfunctionsecret" and "callfunctionsomethingelse"
```

Is there a way to get the function names in some kind of list?

```py
# e.g.
['callfunctionsecret','callfunctionsomethingelse']
```

So far I've only gotten to the point where I can access the function object with

```py
print(script.exports.__getattrs__(callfunctionsecret))
```

but that requires us to know the function name first which defeats the purpose of listing all the function names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen, this is not documented and there isn't an explicit method for this. `ScriptExports` as class does not contain any useful information or methods for this purpose. However, if you search [frida-gum's code](https://github.com/frida/frida-gum/blob/56dd9ba3ee9a5511b4b0c629394bf122775f1ab7/bindings/gumjs/runtime/message-dispatcher.js#L64) there is such an operation serving this purpose, `list`. One could trigger this operation and get all rpc exports like this:

*agent.js*

```js
function callSecretFun(n) {
        return n*100
}

rpc.exports = {
        callfunctionsecret: callSecretFun,
        fun1: function() {send("fun1"); return 1000},
        fun2: function() {send("fun2")}
}
```

*agent.py*

```py
import sys
import frida

session = frida.attach("hello")
with open("agent.js", "r") as f:
    script = session.create_script(f.read())
script.load()
rpc_exports = script._rpc_request('list') # send an rpc request to list rpc exports
print(rpc_exports)
sys.stdin.read()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 agent.py
['callfunctionsecret', 'fun1', 'fun2']
```